# Latest Ruby version not available via RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have RVM installed on OSX. I update it with

```
rvm get stable
```

then ask to see a list of known rubies:

```
rvm list known
```

However, although the latest release is 2.2.2 (as of over a month ago), I cannot see 2.2.2 in the list:

```
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-head] # security released on head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551]
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p643]
[ruby-]2.1.4
[ruby-]2.1[.5]
[ruby-]2.2[.1]
[ruby-]2.2-head
ruby-head
```

No errors are apparent, and all seems to work and update properly. Is 2.2.2 simply not available via RVM right now (in which case where do I check online to find a list of available rubies), or is there a reason this might go wrong on my machine?

Comment: I think it means there is no precompiled ruby 2.2.2 for OSX. But if you run `rvm install 2.2.2` it will install ruby from source code.

Comment: Strange... on Linux I had 2.1.[6] and 2.2.[2] available; they disappeared when I updated RVM itself. My list now looks like yours.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Ah, yes. I just tried `rvm install 2.2.2` and it worked, saying exactly that, then compiling from source. Not sure why it would not be available as a precompiled version, though.